# Does retrofit automatically unzip GZIP files?

Tags: android, gzip, retrofit, unzip

I get from the server side GZIP file.
How should I unzip this or can retrofit automatically do this?

Comment: it does it automatically. P.S I have read all Retrofit code to build my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Answer (score 3):

Gzip files - no. Gzip HTTP streams - yes.

Retrofit uses OkHttp for its communications and recent versions of OkHttp handle HTTP `Transfer-Encoding: gzip` transparently. You don't have to do anything about it.